# Have Vite exclude specific files in a dependency

Tags: ionic-framework, vite, rollupjs

I have an Ionic React app that I'm building with Vite.

Vite is pulling in some Ionic dependencies that are unnecessary:

- `@ionic/core/components/popover.js`
- `@ionic/core/components/action-sheet.js`

I don't use these in my app; they are being pulled in because they are dependencies of `ion-select.js`, and the tree-shaking isn't sophisticated enough to remove them.

So I would like to somehow manually specify that these two files not be bundled in my app.

I thought I could use the Rollup config, but `exclude` only handles modules, not specific files in modules.

The `rollup-multi-entry` plugin has [an exclude option](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/multi-entry#include-and-exclude), so I tried that:

```
  rollupOptions: {
    // input is configured by rollup-multi-entry.
    // This is used to exclude unneeded bundled dependencies.
    input: {
      include: ['src/main.tsx'],
      exclude: ['**/node_modules/@ionic/core/components/popover.js'],
    },
```

However, even with this config, `popover.js` is still included in the app bundle.

How can I configure Vite to exclude specific files that are being bundled?

Comment: If you remove them, non-select won't work properly, will it?

Comment: @EricMORAND It will work fine, because these are optional interfaces that I don't use (tree-shaking just doesn't know that); I am using the alert interface (which I will not remove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are confident that that your code will work and doesn't use `ion-select.js` file in any way, then you can do this using aliases by substituting a fake module. (*Diclaimer: This is micro-optimization and should be avoided as much as possible, I don't really recommend them unless they are really causing problems for you).*

All you have to do is create a stub for these specific files in question and use the `resolve.alias` to point these imports to the mock files.

```
import path from 'node:path';

// vite.config.js
export default {
  // config options

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@ionic/core/components/popover.js': path.join(process.cwd(), 'mock1.js'),
      '@ionic/core/components/action-sheet.js': path.join(process.cwd(), 'mock2.js')
    },
  },
}
```

Create two files viz. `mock1.js` and `mock2.js` inside the root directory. Export whatever values that the original modules `poperover.js` and `action-sheet.js` are exporting. Just that those could be literally empty strings.

Keep in mind that there is a good reason why tree-shaking is not working. The most common being that Vite/Rollup thinks that import of these files could be causing some side-effects (e.g. these files could be doing plain side-effect import like `import '@ionic/core/global.js'` or doing some computation to mutate the global `window`/`globalThis` object). Test extensively before you resort to this.